# Ignoring a single fixture file while seeding database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, seeding

I am hosting a project on heroku, written in rails.
I have a fixture file (comments.yml) that I use during testing, but which I do not want to include when seeding my database (via 'heroku run rails db:seed').

How can I communicate to heroku that I want it to ignore 'comments.yml' when seeding?

Comment: Can you put the contents of `seed.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use environment variables and control it in your seed script:

```
rake db:seed comments=true
```

and later in your `seeds.rb`:

```
unless ENV["comments"]
```